# In Python (and attrs), can I export a field to yaml using a different name?

Tags: python, yaml

I would like to modify a field name, but only when exporting to yaml. For instance:

```
import attrs
import yaml
from attr import fields, field
from attrs import define

@define
class Task:
    id: int

@define
class Data:
    all_tasks: List[Task]
    x: int = field(default=5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_of_tasks = [Task(1), Task(2), Task(3),]

    d = Data(list_of_tasks, 10)
    print(yaml.dump(attrs.asdict(d)))
```

Running this code I get

```
all_tasks:
- id: 1
- id: 2
- id: 3
x: 10
```

I would like to keep the variable name in the code as `all_tasks`, but change it in the yaml to just `tasks`. I generic answer is preferable, since there are several fields to change.

**The underlying issue:**

The underlying issue is that I have a "list of tasks" and calling that variable just "tasks" makes it very similar to a single "task", so I usually rename it to something else. That said, when exporting/importing from YAML, just "tasks" looks much better (for configuration purposes and for non-code aware people.

If there is a good way to do this without attrs, I will also accept that.

Answer (score 0):

PyYAML doesn't support this out-of-the-box, but you can write custom representers to do it. Here's an example of a decorator you can use to change field names, without `attrs` because I don't know it:

```py
import yaml, sys

class yamlTranslate(object):
    def __init__(self, **mappings):
        self.mappings = mappings

    def __call__(self, cls):
        def to_yaml(dumper, data):
            raw = vars(data)
            for key, value in self.mappings.items():
                subject = raw[key]
                del(raw[key])
                raw[value] = subject
            return dumper.represent_mapping("tag:yaml.org,2002:map", raw)
        yaml.SafeDumper.add_representer(cls, to_yaml)
        return cls

@yamlTranslate()
class Task:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

@yamlTranslate(all_tasks = "tasks")
class Data:
    def __init__(self, all_tasks, x):
        self.all_tasks = all_tasks
        self.x = x

list_of_tasks = [Task(1), Task(2), Task(3),]

d = Data(list_of_tasks, 10)
yaml.safe_dump(d, sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```yaml
tasks:
- id: 1
- id: 2
- id: 3
x: 10
```

I use `vars` which isn't recursive, so the `Task` class also needs `@yamlTranslate()` to define a representer for it.